# When on the remote server, my js file cannot access the svg image. But on my local host it works fine

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, icons

I've a js file in my js folder. I've a SVG image in my image folder. I'm trying to acces my image when the page loads (`document.addEventListener('domContentLoaded', (e) => {})`) through this js file but it can't reach the image.

The strange thing is that on Live Server it works, while on Github pages it doesn't work, while offline it doesn't work either... I don't understand.

The path is perfect, but depending on where the upload takes place (live server, offline or GitHub pages) it bugs and the image is not displayed!

[image: my folder structure - where the image is coming from:]

After getting all my IDs and data-atributes from HTML I creating the map and `customIcon`:

```
let map = L.map('map')
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
}).addTo(map);

let customIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: '../images/icon-location.svg',
    iconSize: [32, 40],
    iconAnchor: [10, 41],
    popupAnchor: [2, -40]
});
```

The path as you can see is correct. I insert the icon in my `document.addEventListener('domContentLoaded', (e) => {}`) below. Everything works but the icon:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    map.setView([40.7128, -74.0060], 20);
    L.marker([40.7128, -74.0060], { icon: customIcon }).addTo(map);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }).addTo(map);

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(async function (position) {
            let latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            let longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            map.setView([latitude, longitude], 20);
            L.marker([latitude, longitude], { icon: customIcon }).addTo(map);

            const url = `https://geo.ipify.org/api/v1?apiKey=${apiKey}&lat=${latitude}&lon=${longitude}`;

            try {
                const response = await fetch(url);
                const data = await response.json();

                IPLocation.textContent = data.ip
                dataTimezone.textContent = data.location.timezone
                dataISP.textContent = data.isp
                dataLocation.textContent = `${data.location.country}, ${data.location.region}, ${data.location.postalCode}`
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[my site on GitHub Pages](https://gustavo361.github.io/IP-Address-Tracker/)
Could you help me?

Comment: No, the path is incorrect. `../images/icon-location.svg` resolves to `https://gustavo361.github.io/images/icon-location.svg` instead of the correct `https://gustavo361.github.io/IP-Address-Tracker/images/icon-location.svg`.